# Is there any way to track User logins without simplemembership in mvc3 application?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc-3

Basically I'm working with an existing live MVC 3 application which has no way of tracking user logins/Activity.
It has been operating for some time now, so I cannot introduce Simplemembership and would be reluctant to start adding, out of the box solutions/libraries in case it has a knock-on effect elsewhere.

Is there any tutorials or examples out there that show adding a "History" table for example and how to populate it ?
Please note this is a asp.net MVC 3 applicatio, using Razor views and code first.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a login facility already, you can simply extend your business logic to implement a new   InsertHistory method and call this in the same controller function that handles the POST when logging in.

Comment: so add InsertHistory method to the Accounts controller and call in the POST login ActionResult. Also create a table and class to represent history ?... any examples?

Comment: Exactly that. No examples, sorry. Should not be too difficult to add this however.

Comment: That method will work for logins, but not for general activity once logged in.  For that I would recommend creating an Action Filter.

Comment: All I want is the username and login date/time